# SplashActiviy con peticiones externas

Tags: android, android-studio, android-asynctask

Estoy montando una actividad que haga de Splash en mi aplicación, y está tiene que realizar una serie de comprobaciones, las cuales son peticiones a un servidor web como por ejemplo el login.

Mi problema es que dichas peticiones han de ser asíncronas para que puedan llamar a un servidor web, tal y como funciona la arquitectura de Android, por lo que soy incapaz de concatenar más de una petición, o directamente que la primera (login) me devuelva si el usuario se ha logeado o no.

Mis dos primeras peticiones son:

1. Login del usuario, que me devuelve un token de acceso si el login es válido
2. Comprobación si el usuario tiene los privilegios actualizados (si en el servidor han cambiado, tengo que actualizarlos en mi app)

Una vez finalizadas las peticiones, finalizaría el splash y pasaría a la actividad principal.
Por cada petición que realizo, actualizo un text view para informar al usuario de en que punto se encuentra.

He probado a realizar todas las peticiones en un mismo AsynTask, pero tengo el problema de que no puedo actualizar el TextView, se os ocurre alguna manera para hacer esto?

EDIT: Añado las dos clases con las que lo hago actualmente, y con las que obtengo el error de no poder modificar la pantalla desde un hilo que no sea el principal.

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private boolean flag;
    private TextView tvMsg;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        this.tvMsg = findViewById(R.id.splash_msg);
        this.progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (networkInfo == null || !networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            this.tvMsg.setText(R.string.splash_sin_conexion_internet);
            this.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return;
        }

        AbstractPeticionSplash[] peticiones = new AbstractPeticionSplash[3];
        peticiones[0] = new Pet_Login(this, "XXX", "123");
        peticiones[1] = new Pet_Privilegios(this);
        peticiones[2] = new Pet_Configuracion(this);

        this.progressBar.setProgress(0);
        this.progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.GREEN, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        this.tvMsg.setText(R.string.splash_estableciendo_conexion);

        for (AbstractPeticionSplash peticion : peticiones) {
            this.flag = true;
            peticion.onBeforeExecute();
            new LanzadorPeticionAPI(peticion).execute();
            while (this.flag) {
            }
            peticion.onAfterExecute();
        }
    }

    public void nextPeticion() {
        this.flag = false;
    }

    public void showLoginDialog(String msg) {
    }

    public void setMessage(@StringRes int resid) {
        this.tvMsg.setText(resid);
    }

    public void checkComplete() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        tvMsg.setText(R.string.splash_msg_ok);

        final SplashActivity activity = this;
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent(activity, MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 3000);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class AsyncSplash extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private final SplashActivity splashActivity;

    public AsyncSplash(SplashActivity splashActivity) {
        this.splashActivity = splashActivity;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            this.splashActivity.setMessage(R.string.splash_estableciendo_conexion);
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("", "", e);
        }
        String accessToken = login();


        this.splashActivity.setMessage(R.string.splash_check_privilegios_usuario);
        this.splashActivity.setMessage(R.string.splash_upd_privilegios_usuario);
        this.splashActivity.setMessage(R.string.splash_check_configuracion_usuario);
        this.splashActivity.setMessage(R.string.splash_upd_configuracion_usuario);

        this.splashActivity.checkComplete();
        return null;
    }

    private String login() {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = getConnection(KCfgHogar.Api.User.LOGIN);
        String params = "username=XXX&password=123";
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        try {
            urlConnection.getOutputStream().write(params.getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("API", "Error al añadir los parametros " + params + " a la petición " + KCfgHogar.Api.User.LOGIN, e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                String inputLine;

                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                    response.append(inputLine);
                in.close();
                return response.toString();
            } else {
                splashActivity.showLoginDialog("");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("API", "Error al leer la petición " + KCfgHogar.Api.User.LOGIN, e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private HttpURLConnection getConnection(String url) {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            URL urlAux = new URL(url);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlAux.openConnection();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("API", "Error al obtener la url " + url, e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return urlConnection;
    }

    private HttpURLConnection getConnection(String url, String accessToken) {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = getConnection(url);
        if (urlConnection != null)
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", accessToken);
        return urlConnection;
    }
}
```

Comment: Es una tarea? considera agregar lo que has realizado de lo que expones.

Comment: @Elenasys acabo de añadir las dos clases en las que indico como actúo. A qué te refieres con que si es una tarea?

Comment: Creo que deberías plantearlo al revés. Necesitas al menos una variable en la clase de la `Activity` como flag que indicará cuándo terminan las tareas asíncronas. En `onCreate` lanzas tus llamadas asíncronas cambiando el valor del flag cuando terminan y lanzas la tarea de espera. Y en el Task lo único que haces es esperar a que el flag cambie indicando que se ha terminado.

Comment: La Asynctask ha sido deprecada en Android 30 y actualmente Google recomienda corrutinas.  De todas formas si quieres usar Asynctask para realizar la tarea en background y después actualizar la UI, lo que debes hacer es desde el método onPostExecute() de Asynctask (debes hacer override), notificar a tu activity que la tarea ha finalizado y que se actualice, para esto utiliza un Callback (es una interfaz que contiene un método, y que llamarás desde el onPostExecute).

Comment: @ManuelMato he tratado de buscar información sobre las corrutinas pero no he encontrado nada que me ayude a implementarlas, como por ahora tampoco tengo pensado subir a Android 30 no me preocupa utilizar AsyncTask

Comment: @SuperG280 he intentado seguir tu propuesta, he actualizado el post principal con su integración dentro del source, pero aunque ahora pasa por las tres peticiones, no me refresca la pantalla principal. He probado a modificar el TextView tanto en el onPostExecute de la AsyncTask como en el onAfterExecute que me he creado.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas tu problema para actualizar el textview si basa que los estas queriendo actualizar en un hilo en background.

Para actualizar cosas de interfaz de usuario, tiene que ser el UIThread.

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
              
            this.splashActivity.setMessage(R.string.splash_check_privilegios_usuario);
            }
        };
);
```

Creo que tambien existe el :

```
this.splashActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                  
                this.splashActivity.setMessage(R.string.splash_check_privilegios_usuario);
                }
            };);
```

Comment: Correcto, soy consciente de que no se puede modificar, pero tampoco sabía como plantear la solución al problema. Con esta forma de lanzar hilos crees que me valdría? Entiendo que tu propones dentro del run realizar mi petición, pero no veo como se podrían concatenar las peticiones, salvo que las ponga todas juntitas en una sola

Comment: Para hacer una tarea como pedir datos a una base de datos esta bien en un hilo background, pero cuando llege la hora de actualizar tu interfaz de usuario lo haces en el hilo UIThread, Todo dentro del run que esta con el uithread se ejecutara en el ui thread si hay otro codigo mas abajo de eso se ejecutara en el background , lo que no este dentro del run.  Son independientes , solo se usa el uithread para actualizar cosas de interfaz de usuario.